# How do I download .ipa files to iTunes/Mobile Applications during sync?

Tags: itunes, ipad, backup, data-synchronization, ios

I just reinstalled iTunes for the first time in about a year (was having Config.Msi permissioning issues on install) and synced it with my computer. In my iTunes directory, I have a "Mobile Applications" folder with the .ipas of my older apps. How do I get my iTunes to download the rest of my iPad apps into this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Account` → `Purchases` → `Apps` and in the bottom should be a button with a cloud symbol that says `Download All`. It will start downloading all the apps silently, so don't spam the button.

If it finds an error, which happened to me with the "Find my Friends" app, click the X button in the top-left of the app and then click the `Download All` button again.

I left the computer on all night and it finished downloading every one of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your iPad to iTunes, then select File → Devices → Transfer Purchases.

Comment: Didn't work for downloading the .ipas to the computer. I figured it out last night though.